# cron.php failing with errors

Tags: cron

I have a site running `Drupal 6.30` which has started giving errors when it run the hourly call to cron.php.

The cronjob in question is and run as root:

```
0 * * * * wget -O - -q -t 1 http://example.org/cron.php
```

I get the following rather cryptic / truncated message when it runs

```
could not
```

I have looked in system logs and apache logs but do not see anything that would indicate reason for the problem.

Would anyone be able to suggest anywhere else I could look on the system to troubleshoot.

**edit**
additional logs from `administer -> reports -> dblog` around the time the cron fails.

1

```
mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: Access denied for user 'mann'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /var/www/example.org.org/includes/common.inc(1743) : eval()'d code on line 7.
```

2

```
in /var/www/example.org.org/includes/common.inc(1743) : eval()'d code on line 7.
```

3

```
mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /var/www/example.org.org/includes/common.inc(1743) : eval()'d code on line 8.
```

4

```
Cron run exceeded the time limit and was aborted.
```

Comment: Anything in the watchdog table?

Comment: Try also checking the var/log/cron

Comment: @FelixEve forgive me but where would I find that?

Comment: @Vic it's logged to `/var/log/syslog` but there's nothing obvious, just the following but nothing else `Mar 12 05:00:01 host CRON[7894]: (root) CMD (wget -O - -q -t 1 http://example.org/cron.php)`

Comment: I always use the explicit path to wget in case the `PATH` for whomever the crontab is installed as changes.

Comment: As per your first 3 _error_, If I am correctly understand, you have added some *php* code in any *block* or any *page* content of drupal site which is generating error. So, `cron.php` is not working.

Comment: @MPD the cron job runs fine, it just borks

Comment: @JayendraKainthola only things that may have happened when this arose what new content being added.  is there an easy way to get a list of changed or added nodes?   No changes would have been made to backend files

Comment: @JanGeep, you can check content list in admin section. All new created or updated nodes shown in top of list.

Answer (score 1):

View watchdog logs at Administer >> Logs >> Recent log entries. (admin/logs/watchdog)

More details in this post Drupal.org: [Watchdog: monitor your site](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/watchdog)

Comment: Make sure you have the optional core database logging module enabled, without it, nothing (little?) gets written to the watchdog table in the database. You should also check your PHP logs to see if it is something syntax related that has cropped up (this type of error wouldn't show in the apache log).  Or, perhaps run the cron manually, either with the wget from the command line or via the UI in drupal to see if anything else shows up.

Comment: OP updated with some logs

Comment: @Jimajamma I've tried running it manually with `wget -O - -q -t 1 http://example.org/cron.php` but get the same `could not` error